# Let $x$ be a real number, and $n$ be a positive integer. Prove that $\sin^{2n}x=\frac{1}{2^{2n}}\binom{2n}{n}+\frac{(-1)^{n}}{2^{2n-1}}\sum_{k=0}...$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

My problem is: Let $x$ be a real number, and $n$ be a positive integer. Prove that $$\sin^{2n}x=\frac{1}{2^{2n}}\binom{2n}{n}+\frac{(-1)^{n}}{2^{2n-1}}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}(-1)^{k}\cos[2(n-k)x]$$

My plan: Using Euler's formula, $e^{i(2nx)}=\cos(2nx)+i \sin(2nx)$; and Binomial theorem, $$e^{i(2nx)}=(e^{ix})^{2n}=(\cos x+i\sin x)^{2n}=\sum_{k=0}^{2n}\binom{2n}{k}\cos^{2n-k}(x)i^{k}\sin^{k}(x),$$ expanding this, and collecting the real part and the imaginary part; I note that $\binom{2n}{2n}i^{2n}\sin^{2n}(x)=(-1)^{n}\sin^{2n}(x)$ is in the real part. By comparison the real parts in the expansion and in Euler's formula, I can  get $\sin^{2n}(x)$. But I still get stuck in collecting the real part and expressing $\sin^{2n}(x)$ in the required form.

It's great to get suggestions from you!

Comment: Easier to use $$\sin x =\frac1{2i}(e^{ix}-e^{-ix})$$

Comment: You seem to be missing the binomial coefficients in your sum.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Thanks, from your suggestion, I proved it. I forgot to notice that
$\cos[2(n-k)x]=\cos[2(n-(2n-k))x]$ and $\sin[2(n-k)x]=-\sin[2(n-(2n-k))x]$. Thanks!